# What happens to potential when a charged body is placed next to an uncharged conductor?

Tags: potential, conductors, electrical-engineering

I know that the potential of the charged body decreases due to induction however I feel as though I need a more in depth answer. Why does induction cause the potential of the charged body to decrease and further more what happens to the potential of the uncharged conductor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's, for the sake of discussion, assume that the charged body is negatively charged.

As the changed body is approaching the uncharged body, it induces the charge in it or, more specifically for this case, it pushes the electrons of the uncharged body to the opposite (exterior) side, leaving the interior side positively charged.

This positive charge, being closer to the charged body, attracts electrons of the charged body, so that their density on the internal side increases, while their density on the external side decreases.

Now, if we look at the external side of the charged body, the electric field  coming from it has decreased (due to the decreased density of electrons). From that fact, we can conclude that the potential of the charged body has decreased as well, since, if we push a unit charge along a field line (of a weaker field) from the external surface of the charged body to infinity, the required work would be reduced.

If we look at the external side of the uncharged body, we'll see electric field lines coming out due to the negative charge induced there by the charged body. If we push a charge along one of this lines to infinity, we'll have to perform some work, which means that the uncharged body has acquired some potential.

As the two bodies move closer and closer to each other, this charge induction and redistribution continues, so the potential of the charged body will continue decreasing, while the potential of the uncharged body will continue increasing.

If the bodies eventually touch each other and become one, the whole initial  charge will get distributed between them. The resulting potential of the combined body will be smaller than the original potential of the charged body, because the capacitance of the combined body is greater than the capacitance of the original charged body alone, while the charge is the same.

Comment: Thanks alot that really connected with me and made sense . One thing tho, at the external side of the uncharged body you said that we will see electric field lines coming out however shouldn't it be electric field lines coming in since there is a negative charge at the external side of the uncharged body

Comment: @user122343 Absolutely. I was just trying to convey the idea that the lines originate at the surface, without explicitly stating the direction of the field, but I agree that it could be interpreted as field pointing out, which would be incorrect.

Comment: So VF. (or Op) I think of electric potential **at a point** as the work per unit charge we’d get from the field bringing a charged particle from infinity to that point. Or the work per charge we’d do moving (removing) a particle from that point. Or the work (energy) we could get out of the field on a negative unit-charge. 

Im not certain how to think of the “potential of a charged body”, even after reading that. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AlBrown In this question, only one of the bodies is explicitly called a conductor, but, in my answer, I assumed that both bodies are conductors. Of course, all points of a conductor (under static conditions) have the same potential, so the potential of a conductor is equal to the potential of any point of that conductor.

Comment: I have a question. The density of the negative charges decreases on the external side and therefore the electric field there is weaker, and if we maybe push a negative unit charge we do less work, so there is less potential there (actually a more positive potential, but less magnitude). But is this the same for the internal side? In other words, is the potential on both the internal and external sides the same, such that the conductor is still an equipotential surface?

Comment: @prado5083 Sure, under static conditions, all points on the surface of a conductor have the same potential.